# Text-align isn't working for form element

Tags: html, css

Why text-align isn't working for form? I want my form to be aligned to the right. Please help me. Can I do it WITHOUT floats?

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text">
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</header>
```

My css:

```
ul{
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}

ul li{
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

header form{
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dsotpsq4/

Comment: Don't use `display: inline;` on the form.

Comment: It is working, the text is aligned to the right, but as your form is inline it only takes up as much space as it needs so there is no visual difference. Float the form right instead

Comment: Do you want the whole form on the right? If so, you need `float: right;` why don't you want to use `float`?

Comment: *"without floats"* - Why do you not want to use floats...? It reads as *"I need to accomplish this without using the easiest method."*

Comment: see my answer below tested. working

Answer (score 3):

Use flex box on your `<nav>` and add `justify-content:space-between;`

add this code to your css:

```
nav{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
```

See code snippet:

```css
ul{
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}

ul li{
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

header form{
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
}

nav{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text">
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your **entire form** on the right side of the header, correct with this

```
header form{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

Because form is a block and you need to move it to the right as a block

---

If you want **the content** of your form aligned on its right, change and add this

```
header form{
  text-align: right;
}
header form *{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Text align works only with inline and inline-block elements, so you have to say input and button are inline-blocks.

Answer (score 1):

simply wrap your form inside of a span like so:

```
<div class="my-align">
  <span>
    <form>
      <input type="text">
    <form>
  </span>
</div>
```

then in css

```
.my-align{text-align:right;}
.my-align form{text-align:left;}
```

BTW this is only because you do not want to use float.

Answer (score 1):

you should add `position:absolute` and a right margin value to the form tag in the  css ...

```
form{
display: inline;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
}
```

---

Note that Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow, and can overlap other elements ...

---

[W3Schools Explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead.

```
ul{
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}

ul li{
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

header form{
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: But why isn't the form aligned to the right? That's the question. The question also asked if this is possible without floats

Comment: @DavidB because `text-align` is meant for the alignment of text, not a form. Also, you hadn't added that edit when I wrote the answer. Why don't you want to use `float`?

Comment: @DavidB sorry I thought you were the OP with the way you were speaking... By the way `Float the form right instead – DavidB 17 mins ago` er... that was AFTER my answer you're complaining about... don't be `one of those people`!

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

ul {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

header form {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text">
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Read the question. He doesn't want to use floats.

Comment: Easy there @Huelfe, the original question didn't mention floats - that was an edit. Also it's helpful to keep the answer for other people looking for an answer who aren't float-averse...